# How resolve phpize: command not found in centos 6.3?

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos6

My Server is Centos 6.3 , It using php 5.4.
Now i want install oci8 to my server.
But i call commnad `phpize`,It show error: phpize: command not found.

How resolve phpize: command not found in centos 6.3 using php 5.4?

Or, If  not use phpize , Can we build extension by other ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't install php-devel on centos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325109/cant-install-php-devel-on-centos)

Comment: This is a bad question because there's so little info, but this is in all likelihood asking the same thing as the dupe I proposed - especially given the main repo on CentOS wants PHP5.3, and so will complain you already have PHP5.4 installed if you try to just casually install php-devel.

Answer (score 8):

Install the `php[XX]-devel` package.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had to specify the exact path to make it work

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/phpize
```

As per https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/phpize-command-not-found.565021/