# Error Installing php-devel on centos 6.5 and php 5.4

Tags: php, centos6.5

Server is running Centos 6.5 with PHP 5.4.40.

Entering:

```
yum install php-devel
```

Results in the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tngwebhost.com
 * epel: fedora.westmancom.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-devel-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php54w-common-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php54w-common.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-mbstring-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-gd-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-pdo-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-cli-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-xml-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-dba-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php54w-common(x86-64) = 5.4.40-1.w6 for package: php54w-bcmath-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php54w-common.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php54w.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-dba.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-dba.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php54w-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.40-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php54w-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.45-1.w6 will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: php54w-common-5.4.45-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.4.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Another user on SO had the issue when running 5.3, tried variations of their recommendations with no luck. The last two lines of the error make to recommendations but don't want try random commands that may negatively impact the server. Any ideas or more information I can provide?

To note, ultimately trying to install SSH2 but requires php-devel.

Comment: Looks like php-devel is out of date as PHP is way past even 5.4.  Of course, WTH does it (SSH) want PHP?  One more reason to hate CentOS.

Not you.  Just CentOS.  I have to run it too for a couple projects....

Comment: Believe me I hate CentOS. I use Ubuntu for all my projects and thus haven't run into any of these oddities before. Trying to help another however resolve their issues with their server if I can. Sounds like it may be more trouble that it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall all of PHP 5.3.

```
sudo yum erase php-common
```

Should remove all the PHP-5.3 packages.

Comment: As this is a live server, I'd prefer not to delete any packages that could potentially take down the WordPress site. Though presumably it's running 5.4.40 (since that's what the server says) and thus removing 5.3 reminents shouldn't affect that, but running yum erase php-common sounds like it could potentially also damage 5.4 files. Hoping to find a safer alternative to install php-devel and then ultimately ssh2.

Comment: Use **rpm -qa | grep php** to see what you have for PHP

Comment: Each item in the list starts with php54.

Comment: Just the version noted in the first line of my original post: "5.4.40".

Comment: What does **which php** show? And **phpinfo()** through the web server?You may have two versions of PHP installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php-devel by using this command:

for normal user

> $ sudo yum install php54w-devel

for root user

> $ yum install php54w-devel

You see this error due to your php version. I also faced same issue and I tried these code and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to /etc/yum.repos.d. and remove the extra repository that you can see in your error message.

If that doesnt work, try removing php by

`yum remove php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64`

Comment: When opening the directory I see, "CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Media.repo  CentOS-Xen.repo    remi.repo     webtatic-archive.repo
CentOS-CR.repo         CentOS-SCL.repo    epel.repo          remi.repo~    webtatic.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo  epel-testing.repo  remi.repoOLD  webtatic-testing.repo" Are you suggesting that I delete, "webtatic.repo"?

Comment: No. Just try `yum remove php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64` now and then installing php-devel

Comment: Actually yes, do try removing webtatic

Comment: I just tried, "yum remove php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64" and it says, "Package(s) php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 available, but not installed. No Packages marked for removal"

Comment: Did you try removing Webtactic. Centos doesn't recommend it

Comment: I wouldn't want to entirely remove it since presumably it was installed for a reason and may be needed in the future. But if there is a way to temporarily disable it when installing php-devel to resolve the install errors and then re-enable it, I'd be willing to try that.

Comment: Centos doesn't recommend having Webtactic, read on centos official forum. You can remove it

Comment: Right, I saw your previous comment where you suggest that, however as I noted above it was added for a reason by someone and don't want to risk completely removing it incase their is a chance it may negatively affect something now or down the road and as noted that I'd be willing to try to temporarily disable it if their is an option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your packages are conflicting
`Error: php54w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64`

Based off [this forum post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=53596) and the comments above running `rpm -qa | grep -i php` will show you which packages are installed so you can determine if 5.3 is safe to uninstall.  Other tutorials have recommended `yum list installed | grep php` as well.

If you're concerned about a production server (comments about production upgrades aside) then double check the PHP FPM and/or Apache2/nginx config too to check which PHP binaries/runtime are running the site (is it 5.4 or 5.3) before making any changes.

**If you're trying to upgrade PHP**

To resolve the conflict, simply remove the offending package (in this case 5.3), with `yum remove php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64` before re-attempting the 5.5 install.  Assuming your WordPress site is updated and plugins too then it should be 5.4 compat (at least from the past few years anyway).

**If you're trying to add php-devel to build an extension for 5.4**

Since you mentioned the server is reporting its 5.4 (despite having 5.3 still installed too) then you might need to follow [this SO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325109/cant-install-php-devel-on-centos) advice and enable the devel repo for 5.4: `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php54 install php-devel`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Running, "rpm -qa | grep -i php" lists many versions but all begin with php54. Also when running, "yum list installed | grep php" the long list has each line starting with php54. I'm trying to add php-devel to install ssh2. In the last paragraph, I actually found that linked thread and tried that enable repo command before posting this but also got a similar error. Would you recommend instead then I try the yum remove php-common-5.3....?

Comment: I just tried, "yum remove php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64" and it says, "Package(s) php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 available, but not installed. No Packages marked for removal"

Comment: Is your objective to install 5.4 devel?  If so your trace shows its resolving 5.3. Did you enable the repo as per the last paragraph of my suggested solution?

Comment: So my objective is to install ssh2 which on centos requires "php-devel". When trying to install it I'm getting the errors above. Yes, I ran, "yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php54 install php-devel" based on that SO post, earlier this morning first, but didn't work either.

Comment: The error was, "Said, "Error: Package: 1:php54w-pear-1.9.4-7.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php54w-cli >= 5.1.0-1
           Removing: php54w-cli-5.4.40-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php54w-cli = 5.4.40-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-cli-5.4.45-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               Not found
           Updated By: php54w-cli-5.4.45-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php54w-cli = 5.4.45-1.w6"

Comment: You have both remi and webtatic enabled. Both provide the PHP stack. You should choice only one. Notice that "remi" repository also provides most of existing pecl extensions (see http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status) so you don't need to build them (php-pecl-ssh2 in your case). Also notice that PHP 5.4 is EOL, and even if available (with security backports) in "remi", I heartly recommend you to switch to 5.5 (from remi-php55) or 5.6 (from remi-php56)

Comment: @RemiCollet Yes, was hoping, "yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php54 install php-devel" command would choose remi to install the package but that didn't work as noted above. The server was previously running 5.3 and got them at least to 5.4 even though I recommended at least 5.5, but better than nothing. Are you saying "php-pecl-ssh2" is already installed (but not enabled in 5.4?) I haven't found any record of that.

Comment: yum remove 'php54*' ; yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 install php-pecl-ssh2

Comment: Or:   yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 update; yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 install php-pecl-ssh2

Comment: @RemiCollet your commands would uninstall 5.4 and install 5.5. As I noted above while I'd also prefer they use 5.5 or 5.6 that isn't currently an option. Hoping someone will be able to help resolve this issue where installing php-devel is not working on 5.4. But thanks though!

Comment: See http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2012/09/03/remirepo-IRC-channel-on-freenode-network

Answer (score 0):

You should run:

```
yum install php54w-devel
```

So when install `php-extension` have error:

```
*-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
```

Just type `*-extension`

Example:

`yum install php-fpm` have error

```
Error: php56u-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

then you should run

```
yum install php56u-fpm
```

The reason of this error is you install a php version don't match the system repo version. So yum get a version of the system repo, but this don't compatible with the php version you have installed. When you specific the php version, yum get the right version, so happy!