# cant install php-devel for php 7.4.1

Tags: php, server, configuration, centos, php-7.4

i cannot install php-devel, when i enter:

```
  yum install php-devel


Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:7.4.0-1.el7.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.0-1.el7.remi for package: php-devel-7.4.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-devel-7.4.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.0-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-cli-7.4.1~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular-test)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.1~RC1-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7
           Available: php-cli-5.4.45-17.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.45-17.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.45-18.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.5.38-11.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.38-11.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.5.38-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.5.38-12.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.6.40-13.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.40-13.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-5.6.40-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.40-14.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.2.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.2.24-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.2.25-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.2.25-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.4.0~RC6-15.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.0~RC6-15.el7.remi
           Available: php-cli-7.4.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php74)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 7.4.0-1.el7.remi
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

how to resolve this issue? thanks

Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
php version: PHP 7.4.1RC1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install php-devel on centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325109/cant-install-php-devel-on-centos)

Answer (score 1):

First notice; PHP 7.4.1 is not yet release.

> Installed: php-cli-7.4.1~RC1-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular-test)

This repository should not be enabled (only for DNF users who may want to use modules on EL-7)

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-modular-test
```

And you obviously don't need the repositories providing older PHP versions

```
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php55
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php56
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php70
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php71
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php72
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php73
```

As you have 7.4.1~RC1 you need to enable remi-php74-test

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74-test
yum install php-devel
```

And if you prefer the stable version (7.4.0 for now)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74
yum remove php-common
yum install php-devel
```

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Notice: the **php-devel** package is usually need to build an extension, and most common extensions are available as RPM in the same repository, see [the full list](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status).

```
yum install php-<extension_name>
```

Comment: i am getting this error after "yum install php-devel" centos7
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: cpp = 4.8.5-39.el7
           Installed: cpp-5.1.1-4.fc23.x86_64 (@warning:fedora)
               cpp = 5.1.1-4.fc23
           Available: cpp-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 (base)
               cpp = 4.8.5-39.el7
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7

Comment: Your installation seems a mess, with fedora packages (fc23) installed on centos 7...

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7.2 this worked for me (notice the **remi-php72** )

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-devel autoconf automake
```