# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length

Tags: php, centos, centos7, yum

I recently updated the php, but now I can not get rid from this warning. Also can not roll back the version.
I am running CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core).
How can i downgrade to lower version?

```
# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/intl (/usr/lib64/php/modules/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/intl.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/intl.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.0RC3 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2019 08:30:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

intl module is installed:

```
#yum list installed
php-intl.x86_64                       7.4.0~RC3-5.el7.remi       @remi-modular
```

If i try to downgrade i get many errors, as i understand it is necessary to list all the dependencies to downgrade, such as php-common, php-cli?

```
# yum downgrade php
Error: Package: php-7.3.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
            Need: php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.12-1.el7.remi
            Installed: php-common-7.4.0~RC3-5.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.4.0~RC3-5.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
            Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7
            Available: php-common-5.4.45-17.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-17.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.4.45-18.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-18.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.5.38-11.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-11.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.5.38-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php55)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-12.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.6.40-13.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-13.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-5.6.40-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
                php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-14.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.24-1.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-7.2.25-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.2.25-1.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-7.3.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.11-1.el7.remi
            Available: php-common-7.3.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
                php-common(x86-64) = 7.3.12-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-7.3.12-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
            Need: php-cli(x86-64) = 7.3.12-1.el7.remi
            Installed: php-cli-7.4.0~RC3-5.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-modular)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [cant install php-devel for php 7.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318507/cant-install-php-devel-for-php-7-4-1) especially about repository.

You have to downgrade "all" php packages, so simple way is to use "yum distro-sync".

Also notice that this old issue encounter with RC3 is fixed for a long time, and stable version 7.4.0 is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try choose version you needed and download php source code from [php.net](https://www.php.net/)

Compile and install it [How To Compile And Install PHP Extensions From Source](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/)